# Kodaira's Fields medal citation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

In 1954, Kodaira won the Fields medal. [His citation](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Prizes/Fields/1954/index.html#0x82496a1f_0x0005e9f4) was

> Achieved major results in the theory of harmonic integrals and numerous applications to Kählerian and more specifically to algebraic varieties. He demonstrated, by sheaf cohomology, that such varieties are Hodge manifolds.

Is this intended to be a description of the [Kodaira embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_embedding_theorem)? If so, wouldn't it usually be written the other way around, as "Hodge manifolds are algebraic varieties"? Reading this, it initially sounds like the (trivial) theorem that all smooth projective algebraic varieties are Hodge manifolds.

My best guess is that this is supposed to be a description of the Kodaira embedding theorem as an equivalence, i.e. "the class of algebraic varieties is the class of Hodge manifolds" (as Kodaira does in his [paper on the theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969701?)). But this seems awkward, especially because one should say that the varieties must be smooth projective (or nonsingular and embedded in projective space, as Kodaira does in his paper on the theorem).

So is this a mistake? Is there a good reason for writing it this way that I'm missing? Is this grammatical construction actually commonly used?

Obviously this isn't a hugely important question and may in fact be a silly one, but as these citations are so short and, I imagine, written quite carefully, it's odd to find a mistake or awkward phrasing in one, if that is indeed what that is.

Comment: Are you sure the descriptions there are actually "citations" in any official sense? The one for Serre contains the word (if such it is) "exented", so I don't think they're written *that* carefully.

Comment: @JeremyRickard That typo may have been introduced when it was copied from whatever original form onto the website. That mistake does not appear on the Wikipedia page, where Kodaira's citation is the same there. (I saw them originally on the Wikipedia page, and got the term "citation" from there, but Iinked the IMU website to confirm). If these are not really citations, the Wikipedia page should be edited to clarify...